# How to join two dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.  If the values in dict2 are same then we have to add the values for the matching keys from dict1 and generate a result in the result dictionary as given below.

```
**dict1**                           **dict2**
Id         value                       Id          value
24379      348                         24379       270451
24368      348                         24368       270451
24377       90                         24377       270450
24366       90                         24366       270450
24369       10                         24369       270450   
24300       25

Result:
24379      696
24368      696
24377      190
24366      190
24369      190
```

I have the following logic and would like to optimize this solution:

```
Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (int itemKey in dict1.keys)
{
    result.add (itemKey, dict1.Where(a => dict2.ContainsKey(a.key) 
                                       && dict2.ContiansKey(itemKey) 
                                       && dict2[a.key] == dict2[itemKey])
                              .Sum(a => a.value);
}
```

Comment: *then we have to add the values for the matching keys from dict1*. I don't get that from the result you expect. It seems you are multiplying by two, not adding things together.

Comment: @PatrickHofman `dict2` values for `24379` and `24368` are both `270451`, so OP adds up values from `dict1`, which both happen to be `348`.

Comment: what kind of design is that! its really messed up @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That's what OP wants - perhaps, he has no control over what's in the dictionaries.

Comment: What you have makes very little sense.  Why not have at least one where the key is not in dic2 for an example.

Comment: Dict2 may have more than 2 matching entries or may not have an matching entry

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two steps:

- Prepare a dictionary for looking up the value by `dict2`'s value
- Walk through `dict1`, and insert values from the look-up dictionary

Here is how you can do it:

```
var lookup = dict1
    .Where(p => dict2.ContainsKey(p.Key))
    .GroupBy(p => dict2[p.Key])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(p => p.Value));
var res = dict1.Keys
        .Where(k => dict2.ContainsKey(k))
        .ToDictionary(k => k, k => lookup[dict2[k]]);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/p1tS41)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void DicAddTest()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dic1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { {24379,348}, { 24368, 348 }, { 24377, 90 }, { 24366, 90 } };
    Dictionary<int, int> dic2 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 24379, 270451 }, { 24368, 270451 }, { 24377, 270450 }, { 24366, 270450 } };
    Dictionary<int, int> dicResult = DicAdd(dic1, dic2);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dicResult)
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
public static Dictionary<int, int> DicAdd(Dictionary<int, int> dic1, Dictionary<int, int> dic2)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dicResult = new Dictionary<int, int>(dic1);
    foreach (int k in dic1.Keys.Where(x => dic2.Keys.Contains(x)))
        dicResult[k] = dicResult[k] + dicResult[k];
    return dicResult;
}
```

question is not clear

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> DicAdd2(Dictionary<int, int> dic1, Dictionary<int, int> dic2)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dicResult = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dic1.Where(x => dic2.Keys.Contains(x.Key)))
        dicResult.Add(kvp.Key, 2 * kvp.Value);
    return dicResult;
}
```

Comment: Both codes will **not** produce the same result as the code from the question. Check it with `dic1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { {24379,1}, { 24368, 10 }, { 24377, 100 }, { 24366, 1000 } };`. The result from the question is `{ {24379,11}, { 24368, 11 }, { 24377, 1100 }, { 24366, 1100 } }` and yours is `{ {24379,2}, { 24368, 20 }, { 24377, 200 }, { 24366, 2000 } }`.

Comment: I am completely puzzled why OP accepted this. English portion of the question may not be clear, but C# portion leaves no doubt as to what OP wants. Your code ignores values of `dic2`, multiplying values in `dic1` by `2` instead. This is incorrect, and produces answers that are different from what OP's code produces when you change numbers slightly ([demo](http://ideone.com/p1tS41)).

Comment: If the question is not clear we can vote to close *unclear what you're asking* or leave a comment. Accepting this as the answers makes me feel, the question is not clear for the OP too :o)

Comment: I was testing the solution given today and is not working as expected for this scenario
            Dictionary<int, int> dic1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 24379, 348 }, { 24368, 348 }, { 24377, 90 }, { 24366, 90 }, { 24367, 10 } };
            Dictionary<int, int> dic2 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 24379, 270451 }, { 24368, 270451 }, { 24377, 270450 }, { 24366, 270450 }, { 24367, 270450 } };
For 24367 I am getting 180 instead of 190.

Comment: Not at all clear to me why you would expect 190.  Answer is only as good as the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's easier to do like this, if you are not sure that `dict1` and `dict2` will have the same keys:

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach(var kvp in dict1)
{
    int value;

    if(dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value))
    {
        result[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value * 2;
    }
}
```

This will only add values present in both dictionaries. If your Dictionary is very big, you could perhaps use a [Parallel For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx), or consider use [Hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: cannot modify the collection in the enumeration